# What happens to the existing flows when we enable Lightning run-time for flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

What happens to the existing flows when we enable Lightning run-time for flows?  Do all the flows will run in lightning UI/ or classic UI?
Lightning runtime will apply to specific flows where the changes have been made?

Answer (score 1):

Once enabled, all flows will use the Lightning runtime in all instances except where your flow is running in a Visualforce component.

This is detailed in the help document that for [Lightning Runtime vs. Classic Runtime](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_runtime.htm&type=5)